# How to have prepopulated text in textarea, As Well As 'help hint' text that disappears

Tags: html, forms, textarea

I know how to prepopulate a text area, but I would also like to have certain text in the text area which is there purely to hint at what users should write in a certain section, like:

```
System      ----- stays in text area to be sent with form
-----------
"Enter this specific type of info here" --- disappears when clicking to edit

Bug         ----- stays in text area to be sent with form
-----------   
"Enter only the bug report" --- disappears when clicking to edit
```

So only the user added text and the headings like Bug and System would be sent in the form in which the textarea is part of, not the 'help hint' text.
Yes, I could have different fields but the client wants it all in one textarea. Cant imagine a pain-free way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [the placeholder attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

```
<label for="bug">Bug</label>
<textarea name="bug" id="bug" placeholder="Enter only the bug report"></textarea>
```

It won't work in [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder), but it is advisory information that isn't *needed* to complete the field.

See [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWy34/).

Comment: This looks like its only for a textarea which has no other text in it, you may have misunderstood what I meant. The text area should have headings inside the textarea itself to be sent along with the form, as well as text like your example that disappears when the textarea is edited, purely for advice. (Client wants it that way only) They are not seperate fields, its all in 1 textarea.

Comment: Oh, that isn't possible beyond have the hint text as part of the default value and then rewriting the entire value with JS as soon as the control was interacted with (and before it was read in many cases).

Comment: ah I see, thank you though. Thought it'd be more or less impossible.

Comment: I tried messing around with replacing the textarea value (with hints) with a new value (without hints) onclick but it wouldnt format the text correctly funnily enough.